# R LambertW package - Gaussianize(): Why is transformation not possible? "Error in delta_Taylor(z.init) : kurtosis.y > 0 is not TRUE"

Tags: r, normal-distribution, normalization, normality-assumption

I am using the R package *LambertW*, specifically the function `Gaussianize()`. I have the following vector:

```
> P<-c(2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.5, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0,
2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 6.0, 3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0,
3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0,
3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.5, 6.0, 3.0)
```

That I want to transform:

```
> Gaussianize(P, type="hh", method = "MLE", return.tau.mat = TRUE)
```

However, that gives me the warning:

```
Error in delta_Taylor(z.init) : kurtosis.y > 0 is not TRUE
```

But that is not true, it seems (Kurtosis =4.2; see picture):

```
> test_norm(P)
$seed
[1] 909198

$shapiro.wilk

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  data.test
W = 0.86767, p-value = 4.829e-09


$shapiro.francia

    Shapiro-Francia normality test

data:  data.test
W = 0.86613, p-value = 4.768e-08


$anderson.darling

    Anderson-Darling normality test

data:  data
A = 8.1021, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

[image]

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** This has been fixed in `LambertW` `v0.6.5` (June 8, 2020).

The error comes from [`get_initial_tau()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/LambertW/src/R/get_initial_tau.R), which is called for the `tau.init` argument as part of [`IGMM()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/LambertW/src/R/IGMM.R).

`get_initial_tau()` takes the original data `y` (or `P` in OP case) and transforms it to a centered/scaled version, `z.init <- (y - mu_x) / sigma_x`. But instead of simply using sample mean and standard deviation -- which would be bad for heavy-tailed data --, it uses robust estimators (`median()` and `mad()`). Now it turns out that for your data `mad(P) = 0` --> the normalized data `z.init` is a vector of all `Inf` values --> `kurtosis(z.init) = NaN`, which throws the error.  The error message unfortunately is not the best (I guess I wrongly assumed that `moments::kurtosis()` would throw an error if you pass a vector with `Inf` to it).

This is a corner case bug in the implementation and I can fix it in the future.
Having said that I agree with users before who point out that your particular data seems to be of discrete nature, so it does not really make much sense to `Gaussianize` it.  In that way, the error thrown was a way to point out to you that Gaussianizing the data you have might not be the right thing to do (any data that has `mad = 0` is not generated by a solely continuous data generating process -- there is some discreteness involved).

In any case, a hacky way around the problem is to add tiny noise to `P` so that `mad(P) > 0`.

```
P.tilde <- P + rnorm(length(P), sd=1e-6)
MLE_LambertW(P.tilde, type="hh", distname="normal")

# 
Call: MLE_LambertW(y = P.tilde, distname = "normal", type = "hh")
Estimation method:  MLE 
Input distribution:  normal 
Lambert W type ('h' same tails; 'hh' different tails; 's' skewed):  hh 

 Parameter estimates:
     mu   sigma delta_l delta_r 
3.00011 0.00113 0.81557 2.12878
```

Comment: I can only partially agree on before mentioned comments on the nature of the data: The data is a plant disease index that I defined: It can take the values 1-6. I assign the index to single plants that grow in a pot. For the data analysis I take the median (or mean) of the five plants that grow together in the pot (values in vector P). So, biologically speaking, despite the "discrete look" of my data, it is continuous. 3.3 or 5.27 exists, but I do not measure it*.

Comment: *lets say we measure the weight of 10000 seeds with a balance that can only measure grams but not fractions of grams: Looking at the data of the 10000 seeds we would not state that the data is NOT from a normal distribution (assuming that seed weight is normally distributed) just because there are only integers in the dataset...

Comment: OK, thanks for the background of the data.  I guess it boils down to how much your measurement of the data influences the statistical model you are imposing.  Now in your case, the fact that your measurement tool has such a low precision that you _effectively_ end up with rounded / integer data for continuous processes with (typical) range of 4-5 units, this lack of precision affects your model.  Say, W ~ LogNormal(mu, sigma), but you only observe C = [W], where [W] is the rounded version of W. now Gaussianizing might be a problem of log-transforming a hidden (unobserved) variable.

Comment: More practically speaking: if your measurement tool has a precision of +/- 1 gram , then this is negligible if we are measuring weights of humans for example (it's fine to treat those integers continuous data as the actual data generating process is in the range of ~3,000 - 100,000 grams  (3-100 kgs for humans)).  However, if what you are measuring is itself just only ranging from 1-5 grams, then a +/-1 gram precision is not negligible anymore, but very much changes the nature of the (statistical modeling) problem.

Comment: (Directed at OP) Discreteness or continuity aside, and that is a puzzle, there are at least two further questions. Your index is defined as being bounded and the bounds occur in practice. Any fitted normal or transformed-closer-to-normal distribution will contradict those bounds. Most crucially, what is it that you want to do that requires a marginal normal distribution or will be made to easier to think about by this transformation? Your distribution is not seriously non-normal.

Answer (score 2):

The data are clearly discrete. See

```
hist(P, breaks = 30)
```

Thus, fundamentally, it makes no sense to try to "Gaussianize" this data set. I think you should ask yourself why you want to normalize the data? Is it just to simplify your analysis as you want to use a method that assumes normality?

Indeed, the empirical kurtosis is positive,

```
library(moments)
kurtosis(P)
```

and this seems to be a bug in the package. If you want to find out where exactly the bug is, you need to check the code associated to the functions `Gaussianize` and `delta_Taylor`.

Comment: Remember that some people subtract 3 from the kurtosis and call that the kurtosis. Other people add 3 to the kurtosis and call that the kurtosis. I haven't looked at the code here to find out which definition is being used.

Comment: @NickCox Indeed. In this case, `kurtosis(P)` is `4.183223`, so it seems to be a bug one of those functions. The function `delta_Taylor` uses `kurtosis(y)`, but I think it is something else.

Comment: I confirm with quite different software that the kurtosis (without subtracting 3) is as you report. I agree that wanting to transform this variable to normality is a puzzling goal, by the way.

Comment: As kurtosis (the way it's being calculated by you and me) must always be $\ge 1$, it seems likely that the code is using the different definition. I hesitate to cry bug before investigation,

Comment: @NickCox The `LambertW` package returns the same values of kurtosis as the R package `moments`, thus they are using the same usual definition. My guess, and it is just a guess, is that there is a potentially different kind of error inside those functions that produces this message, but, same as you, I am more concerned about the goal of normalizing discrete data.

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: The error message isn't referring to the kurtosis of the input variable; it's some variable created during the process (which has a bunch of -Infs)

Comment: Seey comment above on where the `inf` come from ( it's because of internal normalization of data by the `mad(y)` which for discrete data can be 0.). In any case this case has been fixed in latest version of LambertW on CRAN and https://github.com/gmgeorg/LambertW